# Debugging experimental WebAssembly externref bug in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, webassembly

Warning: as the reference types proposal isn't complete yet, this code will not run without toggling flags or setting in order to enable executing experimental code.

If you are on Google Chrome or a Chromium browser, you will need to enable the following flag:
`chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-webassembly-features`

---

I had set up a simple handwritten Wasm module for personal use. I could've easily written it in JavaScript, but it was easier and made more sense to use Wasm, and since it was a simple, personal script, I wouldn't care if other people couldn't run it.

I had compiled it using wabt's wat2wasm.

The Wasm module was intended to be fed the entire `globalThis` object to import from.
From there, it took four TypedArray constructors: `Uint8Array`, `Uint16Array`, `Uint32Array`, and `BigUint64Array`.

Take note: no code was executed prior to the Wasm, thus there cannot be any interference.

Later, I had realized that that the Wasm wasn't working as intended at all, my math was correct, but the variables were wrong.

I had narrowed my problem down to just this:

```
;; global -> global variable
(import "globalThis" "Uint8Array" (global $Uint8Array externref))

(import "globalThis" "Uint16Array" (global $Uint16Array externref))

(import "globalThis" "Uint32Array" (global $Uint32Array externref))

(import "globalThis" "BigUint64Array" (global $BigUint64Array externref))

;; func -> function
(import "console" "log" (func $console::log (param externref)))

(start $_start)
(func $_start
    global.get $Uint8Array
    call $console::log

    global.get $Uint16Array
    call $console::log

    global.get $Uint32Array
    call $console::log

    global.get $BigUint64Array
    call $console::log
)
```

This Wasm was instantiated like so:

```js
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(
    fetch(
        "test.wasm", {
            mode        : "same-origin",
            credentials : "omit",
            cache       : "no-store",
            redirect    : "error",
            referrer    : "no-referrer"
        }
    ), globalThis
).catch( console.error );
```

The interesting problem is that the logs all say the same thing: `Uint8Array`.

I was dumbfounded. This has to be literally impossible. The JavaScript file itself was not cached, the WebAssembly was being fetched with "no-cache," the web page itself wasn't cached.

Then I thought, because I was using XHTML, maybe it didn't happen in HTML files. It did there too.

I tried converting the Wasm file to a TypedArray and just using `WebAssembly.instantiate`, suddenly, it worked flawlessly.

At this point the server must be serving the wrong file, because the further I go, the more this seems like nonsense.

I almost want to say that this is a Chromium browser or V8 runtime error, but I need to narrow it down a bit more before I blindly attempt to present this as a bug.

I have set up two different versions of the same code, on [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@xxpertHacker/TypedArrays), and on [CodeSandBox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-resonance-107vk), so that hopefully someone can try running it themself, to confirm the bug, and maybe attempt to debug where I went wrong.

(Could this be a problem with Repl.it's server?)

Comment: I tried running your test cases on both platforms. In both cases I see several alerts, with the expected results. Uint8Array, Uint16Array, Uint32Array....

Comment: @alexp That is interesting, maybe it's a caching issue on my end?

Comment: @alexp I'm getting Uint8 on the Repl test, and everything on the CodeSandBox.

Comment: It seems sporadic and non-deterministic. Once it happens on Repl, it seems to affect the other two tests afterward, without changing the source.
And none of it is cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a compiler bug fixed by Chromium in
https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/v8/v8/+/2551100.

This was the response that I had gotten from one of the developers:

> This is indeed a timing issue that has been fixed in https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/v8/v8/+/2551100. The problem happens when there are only imported globals, and compilation of the WebAssembly functions finishes before the stream actually finishes. In this case, the offset calculation happens after the compiler uses the offsets, and therefore produces incorrect code.
>
> A workaround is to define one global that is not imported, as this causes the offset calculation to happen earlier.

Seems like sending a small module that only imports globals instead of functions was breaking the code.

Their code had a threading race condition between the stream and the compiler.